# OpenLayers で設置しているマーカーが全て収まるようにズーム倍率を変更するには？

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers

OpenStreetMap と OpenLayers でマップ上に複数のマーカーを設置しています。

このマーカーの位置は変動するので、マップ表示時に全てのマーカーが見えるよう Google Maps API の `fitBounds` メソッドのようなものを実現したいと思っています。

OpenLayers でこのような機能は提供されているのでしょうか？ 一応探してはみたのですが見つけることはできませんでした。

代替案等ありましたら、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

だいたいこんな感じになると思います。

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
for (marker : yourMarkers) {
  bounds.extend(marker.lonlat.transform(your_projection));
}
map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
```